# Can you take the results of a dynamic query CTE based on parameters and feed it to another CTE?

Tags: conditional-statements, nested, common-table-expression, resultset, multiple-results

This is just a generic question.
I have a CTE1 that takes a parameter.  It has a dense rank in the select statement and RN<5 in the where statement, so that essentially it runs 5 times and gives me a set of results.  So it spits out 101,102,103,104,105.

I have another CTE2. that can check some conditions and gives me a result.

Essentially I want CTE1 to do its thing and give me my five numbers, then I want to send each number (from those results) to CTE2 and for each number do its check and give me a result on that.

In the end I would have something like
101 - true
102 - true
103 - false
104 - true
105 - true

Is this possible?

I have tried multiple CTE versions with subcte's and recursive and it just seems like it isn't possible.